# How to create a bootstrap tooltip on mouseover event over a table cell in MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a page that shows just a table.
I'm looking for the way of creating a tooltip with bootstrap that will be triggered when a user put a mouse over a certain cell.

I have something like that on my page:

```
foreach(var item in @Model)
{
   <tr><td>item.Total</td></tr>
}
```

How can I use a tooltip bootstrap here?

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the corresponding **bootstrap.css** and **bootstrap.js** files, and reference those files (*you might have already done this, but your question doesn't state that*).

Then, adding on to what you've provided:

```
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap ToolTip Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>

        foreach(var item in @Model)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.ToString())
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        item.Total
                    </td>
                 </tr>
            }
            else
            {
                <tr>
                    <td title="This is a title" data-toggle="tooltip">
                        item.Total
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </table>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ojbk0e8o/) to provide a visual.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you. This displays tooltip for each Total cell. But some cells are just empty. How can I modify it, so the tooltip is displayed only for the cell with the data in it?